# white space/gap issue while sliding in custom content slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a custom content slider.Almost there, but having a issue with background white while scrolling.

There is a gap or space created between each slider.

I have created a fiddle so that you can view the slider.

```
<ul id="slider">
    <li class="case_study" id="case_study1">Div Slide 1 <div class="right"></div></li>
    <li class="case_study" id="case_study2">Div Slide 2 <div class="right"></div></li>
    <li class="case_study" id="case_study3">Div Slide 3 <div class="right"></div></li>
</ul>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/6S6KT/2/

Full Screen : http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/6S6KT/2/embedded/result/

Please suggest.

Comment: your problem is you are animating the second one AFTER the first one has finished animating - simply move the -100% for the second one beneath the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#slider li.case_study:first-child').animate({
    left: '-100%'
}, 300, function () { // The command function is a **CALLBACK**
    $('#slider li.case_study:first-child').css('left', '100%');
```

Your code above does what it is meant to do - I have added a comment where you are using a callback.

A callback fires when the first item has finished - so at the moment your script moves the first div 100% to the left THEN it adds the second div to the screen and animates it to the left.

You want everything to happen in your `.animate({},300)` clause - as follows:

Append second div to the right of first div - then move both divs to the left at the same time.

Have a go - if you get stuck then post your new code - but see if you can work it out yourself - it will help you learn faster!

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. I have understood the logic now but when I am implementing in the code then it is getting messed up.My intention was to move the first slide in different speed and then second one in different speed so I have kept 2 animate functions.

Comment: :) that was because of the speed limit. Latest update is http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/6S6KT/17/ which works fine.

Comment: I will be doing the previous button now. Thanks once again.

Comment: In your CSS dont forget list-style:none -> that will remove the 'dot'!

Comment: Yes I need to do that.Also having a small problem with the previous scrolling.The current slide moves from left to right but the previous slide should come from left to right whereas it is moving from right to left.The direction is wrong.  http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/6S6KT/22/

Comment: Now I have to do the adaptive height set for the slider instead giving it fixed height.Latest -- http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/6S6KT/24/